# How can I check what SNAPSHOT build (unique build version) maven used?

Tags: maven, maven-3, snapshot

I am working with SNAPSHOT versions. I just build and installed one locally, but I have a hunch maven is still opting to use the slightly older remote version when I'm building a downstream project that depends on the SNAPSHOT. Is there a way to check what SNAPSHOT build (the one from the remote repo or the newer one from my local repo) maven ended up using?

NB: I'm running `mvn clean install -U` on the downstream project...

Comment: try mvn -X clean install, which will provide a _LOT_ of debug output. Within that output, you should see which timestamp the SNAPSHOT dependency has while it is downloaded. With that information, you should be able to indentify which one is used. Granted, this only works for maven 3, hence timestamped SNAPSHOT have been introduced with Version 3.

Answer (score 0):

Look files : .lastUpdated and x.x.SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata-local.xml 
You have a vesion used by maven